# Rendering js.erb in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

i want to try my js.erb if it is working?

here my view posts/index to trigger

```
 <%= link_to "Like", {:controller => 'post', :id => post , :action =>'like'}, class: "btn btn-danger btn-xs", remote: true %>
```

my post controller

```
def like
@user = current_user
@post.liked_by(@user)
redirect_to posts_path
respond_to do |format|
  format.html {redirect_to posts_path}
  format.js { render :action => 'stablelike' }

end
end
```

and this is my js.erb to test

```
alert("working");
```

and this is my error: when i inspect my Chrome

## AbstractController::DoubleRenderError at /post/like/85

> Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and return".

### app/controllers/posts_controller.rb, line 83

````
 ``` ruby
 78       @user = current_user
 79       @post.liked_by(@user)
 80       redirect_to posts_path
 81       respond_to do |format|
 82         format.html {redirect_to posts_path}
````

> 83         format.js { render :action => 'stablelike' }
>        84
>        85       end
>        86     end
>        87

Comment: why you use redirect two times in action `like`

Comment: oh i see thats my error

Comment: i dont have error now but the alert not working?

Comment: uzaif can i feed you back?

Comment: @GeromeJohnPangan, Inspect the network tab and see if the XHR was successful.

Comment: @GeromeJohnPangan what is file  name of `js.erb`

Comment: @GeromeJohnPangan Updated the answer. See if it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a controller action, neither `render` nor `redirect_to` stops the execution of the action. That is why you're getting a `DoubleRenderError`. Remove the first `redirect_to` and everything should be fine.

```
def like
  @user = current_user
  @post.liked_by(@user) # I am unsure what you're trying to accomplish here
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to posts_path }
    format.js { render :stablelike }
  end
end
```

If this doesn't work, probably you have not setup `stablelike` action to respond to `xhr` requests. You can do that by

```
def stablelike
  respond_to  do |format|
    # other formats
    format.js # by default looks for `stablelike.js.erb`
  end
end
```